# Octopus set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Tags: environment-variables, octopus, aspnetcore-environment

```
Windows 10
Octopus v2018.4.3
```

Has anyone successfully used `Octopus` to set the system environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` ?

Comment: Are you facing any problem in that ?

Answer (score 0):

To set system variable from octopus, you need to run bash command for that

Command : `setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "C:\foo" /M`